# Can halacha of Eidim Zomemim be applied in today's times? (ex: $ cases)

Tags: beit-din-court, edim-witnesses, maseches-makos

> **Scenario**: Reuven & Shimon are at the [Beth Din of America](https://bethdin.org/) in Manhattan and are testifying that Levi completely wrecked Yehuda's Manhattan apartment on March 17.
>
> **Suddenly**: Dan & Naftali come in mid-testimony and say "We don't know whether or not Levi wrecked Yehuda's apartment, but we're here to testify that that **you were with us in LA on March 17**."

This sounds like a textbook case of Eidim Zomemim (conspiring witnesses) right out of the first perek of Makkos!

### Now:

**For death/ lashes/ fines** -  there's no court of 23 or Sanhedrin nowadays which would be able to administer death/ lashes/ fines.

### But:

In **monetary** cases... (which **ARE** still applicable nowadays)

**Is it possible for a case of Eidim Zomemim to happen in today's times?**

Comment: We don't levy fines nowadays in general (for example a modern court won't make you pay back double for theft).

Comment: @DoubleAA right- but is paying someone back for causing monetary damage considered a fine? (acc to R' Akiva = yes, but that's because he says Eidim Zomemim is a *k'nas* implication being others don't view it as a *k'nas*)

Comment: hm? What monetary damage did the zomemin do?

Comment: @DoubleAA none and that's why you're right that it makes sense that it's a *k'nas* (see kouty's answer below who quotes the Rema who writes as such) although then I don't understand why R' Akiva's *shita* who's seemingly presented as a novel *da'as yachid* https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.2b.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: In that same first perek of makkos we learn that the punishment for eidim zomemim is considered a fine (knas) not a monetary case (mamon). Amazingly, it seems this is the case even if the punishment is something other than paying (e.g. lashes or even death)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes.

**Shulchan Aruch**, [Choshen Mishpat 38:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.38.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> שנים שהעידו באחד שחייב לפלוני מנה ובאו שנים והכחישום או הזימום ה"ז פטור
>
> if the witnesses he needs to pay 100 ($) are zomemim, he needs not to pay.

### However

Nowadays the punishment of Eidim Zomemim is **NOT** applied because it's a *k'nas* and we cannot enforce *dinei knasot* in today's times. Nonetheless the Eidim Zomemim are made to be unfit witnesses.

**Rema** (there):

> כי אע"פ שאין דנין דין עדים זוממים האידנא משום שהוא קנס, מכל מקום איכא נפקותא דעד זומם פסול להעיד כמו שנתבאר לעיל סי' ל"ד

**The unfitness of Edim zomemim is not a knas, but their punishment is a knas.**

See extended discussions about additional consequences of the din Zomemim nowadays in comments around the Tur and SA in the there.

Comment: A little confused: on the one hand the SA says that Eidim Zomemim **does** exist nowadays (the case of $100) but on the other hand the Rema says since it's a *k'nas*  it **does not** exists nowadays. Machlokes SA vs Rema?

Comment: No there isn't machloket. The unfitness of Edim zomemim is not a knas, but their punishment is a knas.

Comment: gotcha thanks! Will IH also check out the Tur/ surrounding commentaries 